# Since SWIG doesn't appear to work with managed C++/CLI, what else can I use (to comm with Java)?

Tags: java, c++-cli, swig

I have a Java GUI application that has been interacting quite nicely with a standard C++ based DLL on the back end via SWIG-generated files. The back end program is currently a combination of C++ and managed C++/CLI. The problem is that we may eventually port all of it to C++/CLI.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I've been able to tell, SWIG currently doesn't work with C++/CLI and there are no plans to make it do so. I imagine that I could do write JNI code to make it work. But using SWIG was a whole lot easier. So what other options are there? The simpler to use, the better.

Comment: I guess [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/) could be extended easily to emit those funky operators needed by C++/CLI, interesting.

Comment: Since it looks like C++/CLI doesn't have something like `NewGlobalRef()`, we'd have to do it manually, something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/4695939/523744 but it looks doable...

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct to say that SWIG won't work with C++/CLI... You should be able to use the generated interop stubs exactly the same way you did. I didn't encounter a scenario where switching on the CLR support broke existing well formed C++ code...

Comment: I'm not talking about a simple matter of activating the /clr support option in project properties. The conversion would be a complete rewrite from code that uses lots of * pointers and calls #include <stdio.h> to one that refers to methods in Object^ with -> and is using the System namespace. It may be that my attempts to run swig on those kinds of files was flawed or there was something wrong with the files. But I hadn't seen any documentation suggesting that kind of C++ code would be compatible with SWIG.

Comment: I see. SWIG cannot parse files which use C++/CLI syntax extensions, that's right.